# UAV development platform

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

What is UAV development platform? For example, STM UAV, Intel, Parrot and so on. I searched on Google, but couldn't get its exact meaning.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you only interested in commercial platforms? There are [open source platforms](https://opensource.com/article/18/2/drone-projects) too that may be easier to study, in particular [PX4](https://px4.io/case-studies/).

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, can you narrow it down a bit and perhaps tell us what you are developing a UAV for and what you are looking for in a platform? FWIW with enough engineering effort _anything_ can be used as a development platform.

Comment: I want to develop micro unmanned vehicle (MAV), so I would like to know which MAV platforms are exist and what is UAV development platform (is it only hardware, or only software or both of them)?